# How to recode the jquery load with ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
$main.load(href + " main>*");
```

what that does is load the page I give it and only the contents inside "main" tag including "main".  What I want to do is add the progress bar while it's loading so I saw that this is possible only with .ajax so I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
            xhr: function()
            {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //Download progress
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        //Do something with download progress
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: href + " main>*",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                //Do something success-ish                                      
            }
        });
```

but that doesn't work the same.  So how do I go about loading a page's content and only it's "main" content?

Comment: Not really clear what the question is. How to get `main` using `$.axax`?

Comment: @charlietfl yes that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what `.load()` does is fill the selected element(s) with the content loaded with an optional filter, which basically discards everything but what matches the filter.

```
...
url: href,
success: function(data){
    var content = $(data).find("main>*");// if main is a child of the body tag will fail, try .filter() instead
    $main.empty().append(content);                              
}
...
```

Comment: Tried it with .filter() because it is a child of the body tag but i got an empty page